# Make search URL search engine friendly: hash -> what?

Tags: http, url-rewriting, web, seo

I am developing a flight search engine for a customer, and currently the URLs look as follows (*ad* = destination airport, *ao* = origin airport, dates and number of passengers are not specified here):

http://example.com/#ad=S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+Todos+os+aeroportos+(SAO),+Brasil&ao=Recife+-+Guararapes+Intl+(REC),+Brasil

My customer wants to make search pages more search engine friendly (SEO). The idea is that Brazilians who are looking for flights from, say, SAO to REC by e.g. Google should have a higher chance of finding that particular flight search engine.

The first step is probably replacing the fragment identifier (#) by a query string (?). The server then dynamically generates nice text content that can be viewed without JavaScript (search results would still be loaded via XHR). In my opinion, that makes a lot of sense.

Now, to make the URLs more search engine friendly:

- (A) My customer proposes adding additional keywords into the URL, something like:

  http://example.com?flights+to+Porto+Alegre&S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+Todos+os+aeroportos+(SAO),+Brasil&ao=Recife+-+Guararapes+Intl+(REC),+Brasil
- (B) I propose adding a slug instead, which can easily be internationalized, and which is good to read also for humans. Example:

  http://example.com/pt_BR?ad=REC&ao=SAO/voos_de_Sao_Paulo_para_Recife
- (C) Or, perhaps without a slug (but - due to parsability - only for a limited parameter set, which has the disadvantage of limiting sharing of URLs by users):

  http://example.com/pt_BR/voos_de_Sao_Paulo_(SAO)_para_Recife_(REC)

What do you suggest? Any examples of good URLs for similar use cases?

That all being said: I understand that links from highly ranked pages are still the most important ranking measure. In the end, I wonder if all that complexity really is worth the effort. When I look at Google's own search pages, then they are rather simple. For example, there is no summary of the search query in a H1 tag, just as my customer wants. Of course, Google doesn't search itself...

Comment: Note to me: It's probably best to leave out the parentheses in the URL as [parentheses are reserved characters](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). Some users carelessly put URLs in parentheses, for example, leading to trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- don't use `_` (underscore) to delimit words. [Google interprets](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQcSFsQyct8) `hello_world` as one word but `hello-world` as two words.
- don't put your *human readable* keywords in the query string (after the `?`). Instead make it a normal URL `http://example.com/pt_BR/search/voos-de-Sao-Paulo-(SAO)-para-Recife-(REC)`

I would go for a something like: `http://example.com/pt_BR/2012-10-28/voos-de-Sao-Paulo-(SAO)-para-Recife-(REC)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, consider that there are lots of optional parameters. For example, it is possible to specify several leave and several return dates, and it is possible to specify a number of children in addition to a number of adults, etc. So, I think for the full URLs, the query string is unavoidable.

Comment: well, sure, query strings are great for search but not so great got Google (or human readability). I think the *clean* urls should only be used as a starting point for your search (like a landing page). And on a different note, you cannot expect a visitor to fill in all the paramaters in Google and have Google find the exact search result on your site. But that's a different debate all together (Search v.s. Browse)

Comment: True, @simonmenke. We can use this structure for landing pages. But I think it's best then to remove the date and instead put all additional search parameters in a hash tag. I assume that Google cuts of plain hash tags when doing the ranking. So, every time that people publicly share search results for SAO - REC, then the respective landing page will get improved ranking. What do you think?

Comment: You say: "Google interprets hello_world as one word but hello-world as two words." Could you add a source to back up this claim? That would make your answer better.

Comment: Thanks! Just updated your question with the URL. That makes it easier for others to find.